# Changing the Privacy Scope of PHP Class Functions

Tags: php, class, scope, abstract-class

I have an abstract class that extends classes to provide a basic orm function. All the functions it provides are protected to the class so it can decide what fields are made publicly available to outside objects. But recently, I have started working with some smaller data classes that do not require such complexity, and would benefit from having the orm editing functions publicly available and no special functions.

As the naming convention for the functions is sufficient and compact, is there a way to change the existing functions to public (without needing the same class, or an interim extends), or would I have to use the new `traits` feature of php to add an existing class, which contains public versions of the functions that act as an abstraction layer for the internal protected functions?

EDIT:

For the traits method, I was thinking that it would help like this:

```
abstract class ORMClass {
    public function __construct($pk) {}
    protected function __get($k) {}
    protected function __set($k,$v) {}
    protected function save() {}
}

trait publicORM {
    public function __get($k) { return parent::__get($k); }
    public function __set($k,$v) { return parent::__set($k,$v); }
    public function save() { return parent::save(); }
}

class myOrm extends ORMClass {
    use publicORM;
    protected static $table = 'myTable';
}
```

so then I could use `myOrm` like:

```
$myOrm = new myOrm(1);
$myOrm->foo = 'alice'
echo $myOrm->bar;
$myOrm->save();
```

without needing the:

```
public function __get($k) { return parent::__get($k); }
public function __set($k,$v) { return parent::__set($k,$v); }
public function save() { return parent::save(); }
```

to be listed in the class myOrm

Comment: So you have a class with protected methods, and, externally, you would like to modify the class to change some of its methods from protected to public?

Comment: I think the interim class method you mention will turn out to be the best. Create another abstract class that extends your base but has public accessors, and subclass THAT when you want that behavior.

Comment: Talk about overcomplicating things... :)

Comment: Isn't that half the fun?

Comment: You can't change the visibility of a method to make it more visible in PHP.

Comment: @SDC, as of PHP 5.3.2, you can use [`ReflectionMethod::setAccessible`](http://php.net/reflectionmethod.setaccessible) to do so.

Comment: @Charles that works perfectly for my code, wanna post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this was never answered properly, I'm adding Charles answer.

This can be done using PHP's [Reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) library, built in to PHP since version 5. This particular method is fairly hacky:

```
<?php

abstract class BaseClass {
    protected function testMe() {
        echo 'I WORK!';
    }
}

class ConcreteClass extends BaseClass {
    // Class Code
}


$method = new ReflectionMethod('BaseClass', 'testMe');
$method->setAccessible(true);
$method->invoke(new ConcreteClass()); // Prints 'I WORK!'
```

And here is the better method using an interim abstract class that extends the base class but uses public methods:

```
<?php

abstract class BaseClass {
    protected function testMe() {
        echo 'I WORK!';
    }
}

abstract class PublicBaseClass extends BaseClass {
    public function testMe() {
        parent::testMe();
    }
}

class ConcreteClass extends PublicBaseClass {
    // Class Code
}


$obj = new ConcreteClass();
$obj->testMe();
```